# ASP/C# - Sql connectien with update

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
    sql connectie
    string KlasconnectionString = @"DataSource=RICHARD\MSSQLSERVER12;Initial Catalog=MojoGegevens;Integrated Security=True";
    // verbinding 
    SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, KlasconnectionString);
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();

    sql += "update tblOpmaak set Themakleur = 'red'";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(KlasconnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlConnection(sql, conn);
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```

It gives an error at the "conn" in the line: `SqlCommand Cmd = new  SqlConnection(sql, conn);`

Answer (score 1):

By using this line of code(`SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlConnection(sql, conn);`) What you are trying to do is Creating a new connection and assign it to the SqlCommand, Such assignment is invalid and not permitted, This is why it throws the error.
You can create the Command by using the following line:

```
 SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand (sql, conn);
```

**And a Small Advise for you;** Specify the condition in where clause, otherwise the update will affects all rows(Leave it if you want to update all rows).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `SqlCommand`. So, you cant use `New SqlConnection`. Rather you should use `New SqlCommand`

```
SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand (sql, conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlConnection(sql, conn);
```

into

```
SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"DataSource=RICHARD\MSSQLSERVER12;Initial Catalog=MojoGegevens;Integrated Security=True");

    con.Open();
    sql += "update tblOpmaak set Themakleur = 'red'";

    SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();

    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlConnection(sql, conn);
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```